# JavaScript recursive setTimeout scope

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, settimeout, setinterval

This is working fine:

```
let timerId = setTimeout( function tick() {
  this.oneIteration(this.eventsQueue[counter], counter)
  counter++
  if( counter == this.eventsQueue.length ) {
    clearInterval(this.iteartionInterval)
    this.stopBtnClick()
  }
  timerId = setTimeout(tick.bind(this), this.timeoutDelay)
}.bind(this), 100)
```

My question is, how would it be possible to get rid of various

> .bind(this)

making use of a more modern approach with arrow functions. A sample of this code is published here: [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-keldysh-j0prt?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:332-668)

Comment: you can try using the arrow functions .?

Comment: `const tick = () => {…}; tick();`